# Cannot connect to Cassandra on a cloud server using phpcassa

Tags: php, cloud, cassandra, phpcassa

I have setup a test cloud server (Ubuntu 10.10 on Rackspace) to play with [Cassandra database](http://cassandra.apache.org/) (0.6.8).
I can connect no problem both from within the server and from a computer external to the cloud using the cassandra-cli basic client: I have created and retrieved sample data.

I have then installed phpcassa on the cloud server and on an external computer.

I have created a very simple php program to test the connection:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__) . '/include/thrift/';
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'/packages/cassandra/Cassandra.php';
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'/transport/TSocket.php';
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php';
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'/transport/TFramedTransport.php';
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'/transport/TBufferedTransport.php';

include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/include/phpcassa.php');
include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/include/uuid.php');

echo 'phpcassa test01<br /><br />';
CassandraConn::add_node('184.106.97.245', 9160);

$users = new CassandraCF('Keyspace1', 'Standard2');

try {
    $res = $users->get('jsmith');
    print_r($res);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print CassandraConn::$last_error;
}

echo 'End.'
?>
```

I am using buffered transport.

I can happily connect and read data from within the server (I have also installed LAMP on it):

```
phpcassa test01
Array ( [age] => 42 [first] => John [last] => Smith ) 
End.
```

but not from outside because I am always getting the exception:

```
phpcassa test01
TException: TSocket: Could not connect to 184.106.97.245:9160 (Operation timed out [60])
End.
```

This is my storage-conf.xml file:

```
<Storage>
<ClusterName>Test Cluster</ClusterName>
<AutoBootstrap>false</AutoBootstrap>
<HintedHandoffEnabled>true</HintedHandoffEnabled>
<IndexInterval>128</IndexInterval>
<Keyspaces>
<Keyspace Name="Keyspace1">
  <ColumnFamily Name="Standard1" CompareWith="BytesType"
                KeysCached="1000"
                RowsCached="100"
                RowCacheSavePeriodInSeconds="0"
                KeyCacheSavePeriodInSeconds="3600"/>
  <ColumnFamily Name="Standard2" 
                CompareWith="UTF8Type"
                KeysCached="100%"/>
  <ColumnFamily Name="StandardByUUID1" CompareWith="TimeUUIDType" />
  <ColumnFamily Name="Super1"
                ColumnType="Super"
                CompareWith="BytesType"
                CompareSubcolumnsWith="BytesType" />
  <ColumnFamily Name="Super2"
                ColumnType="Super"
                CompareWith="UTF8Type"
                CompareSubcolumnsWith="UTF8Type"
                RowsCached="10000"
                KeysCached="50%"
                Comment="A column family with supercolumns, whose column and subcolumn names are UTF8 strings"/>
  <ReplicaPlacementStrategy>org.apache.cassandra.locator.RackUnawareStrategy</ReplicaPlacementStrategy>
  <ReplicationFactor>1</ReplicationFactor>
  <EndPointSnitch>org.apache.cassandra.locator.EndPointSnitch</EndPointSnitch>        
</Keyspace>
</Keyspaces>
<Authenticator>org.apache.cassandra.auth.AllowAllAuthenticator</Authenticator>  
<Partitioner>org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner</Partitioner>
<InitialToken></InitialToken>
<SavedCachesDirectory>/var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches</SavedCachesDirectory>
<CommitLogDirectory>/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog</CommitLogDirectory>
<DataFileDirectories>
  <DataFileDirectory>/var/lib/cassandra/data</DataFileDirectory>
</DataFileDirectories>
<Seeds>
  <Seed>184.106.97.245</Seed>
</Seeds>
<RpcTimeoutInMillis>10000</RpcTimeoutInMillis>
<CommitLogRotationThresholdInMB>128</CommitLogRotationThresholdInMB>
<ListenAddress>184.106.97.245</ListenAddress>
<StoragePort>7000</StoragePort>
<ThriftAddress>184.106.97.245</ThriftAddress>
<ThriftPort>9160</ThriftPort>
<ThriftFramedTransport>false</ThriftFramedTransport>
<DiskAccessMode>auto</DiskAccessMode>
<RowWarningThresholdInMB>64</RowWarningThresholdInMB>
<SlicedBufferSizeInKB>64</SlicedBufferSizeInKB>
<FlushDataBufferSizeInMB>32</FlushDataBufferSizeInMB>
<FlushIndexBufferSizeInMB>8</FlushIndexBufferSizeInMB>
<ColumnIndexSizeInKB>64</ColumnIndexSizeInKB>
<MemtableThroughputInMB>64</MemtableThroughputInMB>
<BinaryMemtableThroughputInMB>256</BinaryMemtableThroughputInMB>
<MemtableOperationsInMillions>0.3</MemtableOperationsInMillions>
<MemtableFlushAfterMinutes>60</MemtableFlushAfterMinutes>
<ConcurrentReads>8</ConcurrentReads>
<ConcurrentWrites>32</ConcurrentWrites>
<CommitLogSync>periodic</CommitLogSync>
<CommitLogSyncPeriodInMS>10000</CommitLogSyncPeriodInMS>
<GCGraceSeconds>864000</GCGraceSeconds>
<DoConsistencyChecksBoolean>true</DoConsistencyChecksBoolean>
</Storage>
```

Rackspace support suggested changing the firewall settings but I have no firewall:

```
root@Oahu:~# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any help very much appreciated!!!

Cheers, Rujero

Comment: What is your external machine like? OS, php version, etc.  Is the iptables output from the server or from the external client?

Comment: I have the  same issue, both machines are CentOS 5, PHP 5.3.  The iptables output in my case is the same as above on both machines.  I am using the latest version of the @Tyler Hobbs phpcassa library.

Comment: dmcnelis: Are you using Cassandra 0.7.x?

Answer (score 0):

Access the node (first) with http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraCli