# how to connect to cassandra on a cloud server

Tags: cassandra, rackspace-cloud, cassandra-0.7

I have been trying to connect to a cassandra database on a Rackspace cloud server with no success.

Can anyone shed any light on the last paragraph of this comment from http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/StorageConfiguration

listen_address
Commenting out this property leaves it up to InetAddress.getLocalHost(). This will always do the Right Thing *if* the node is properly configured (hostname, name resolution, etc), and the Right Thing is to use the address associated with the hostname (it might not be: on cloud services you should ensure the private interface is used).

Comment: I posted a comment asking some details on your previous question here but never got an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651519/cannot-connect-to-cassandra-on-a-cloud-server-using-phpcassa

Answer (score 1):

On Rackspace Cloud Servers you will most likely want to listen on eth1 (10.X.X.X), the ServiceNet IP.  This is only accessible to other Cloud Servers inside the same datacenter.  The max throughput of eth1 is twice that of eth0 and you are not charged for the bandwidth.

Please remember that the ServiceNet network is not private so you will still need to restrict access to the ports that you bind to via iptables.

Comment: Thanks but I was actually trying to connect from outside Rackspace. Still haven't figured out why it's failing...